# Attachment file name displays incorrect - Elixir

Tags: elixir, mailman

I have problem in sending email with attachment which file name includes Chinese character by [mailman](https://github.com/kamilc/mailman).

The file name of attachment in email looks incorrect.
What should I do to make file name display as normal in attachment.

[snapshot about attachment with wrong file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOdqy.png)

```
elixir
def compose(reusme_path, resume_name, email, subject, text) do
  %Mailman.Email{
    subject: subject,
    from: "career@xxx.com",
    to: [email], # should be [email] arg
    html: "<html><body>
    <div>#{text}</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img style='width: 200px; height: 200xp;'
      src='https://cavi-cdn.b0.upaiyun.com/resumes/attachments/rX63jEjNq3Zs7hiQKvDBqY5CBl4peBMT/WechatIMG49.jpeg'/>
    </body></html>",
    attachments: [
      Mailman.Attachment.inline!(reusme_path, "#{subject}.pdf")
    ]
  }
end
```

So, How to configure mailman Or what should I do to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: @JustMichael
Would you please do me a favor ? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove `URI.encode` and do just `Mailman.Attachment.inline!(reusme_path, "#{subject}.pdf")`?

Comment: @Dogbert  
If I removed URI.encode, the name of attachment file looks  as snapshot shows.  
May be I should remove URI.encode in question. my mistake.  
PS: if using URI.encode, all the file name are encoded. but after download, the file name is correct.